# Is it possible to set an audit process monitor on WMI via powershell?

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am planning to audit a WMI class to know who accessed the instances or executed method when I pull the report. Can I run power shell to do this kind of logging when such an event triggers?

I searched and found "Process Monitor" but that doesn't show this information.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you would need to enable audit policy. Then you could easily track WMI access from event logs using `Get-EventLog` cmdlet.